# Syntax error in imperative code

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, ocaml

```
exception Error of (string);;
let v = ref true;;
let e = Error("Fail");;
let h = ref false;;
while !h <> true do
  let x = read_int();
  let y = read_int();
  try
    let res = x / y in
    Printf.printf "result = %d" res;
    h := true;
  with
    Division_by_zero -> raise e
done;;
```

returns a syntax error in line "done;;", but I do not know why.

Answer (score 4):

```
let x = read_int();
```

is a toplevel definition, not an expression. The expression form would be

```
let x = read_int() in ...
```

More generally you seem to be very heavily emulating an imperative Algol-like style, which will mostly just confuse you and cause you a lot of pain. You should instead try to write code without mutability, semicolons (which in OCaml is a "sequence operator", not a line/statement terminator) and imperative iteration.

You might also find the JavaScript-like [ReasonML syntax](https://reasonml.github.io/) more familiar and easier to deal with, but it would of course be another thing to set up and OCaml learning resources would have to be translated, so might not be worth the extra hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly propose people suffering from OCaml syntax errors to use a proper indentation tool, such as `ocp-indent` and try indent your code lines.  From the auto-indentation results, you can often find the right places of problems when your code is different from your intention:

```
exception Error of (string);;
let v = ref true;;
let e = Error("Fail");;
let h = ref false;;
while !h <> true do
  let x = read_int();
    let y = read_int();  (* <= this is still in the definition of x *)
      try
        let res = x / y in
        Printf.printf "result = %d" res;
        h := true;
      with
        Division_by_zero -> raise e
done;;
```